# rm_between with multiple markers in an observation

Tags: regex, r, qdapregex

There are some helpful answers on here about using rm_between when each observation has only one instance of the markers. However I have a dataset where I want to extract things in ""'s and some of the observations have multiple instances of that. For example:

Fresh or chilled Atlantic salmon "Salmo salar" and Danube salmon "Hucho hucho"

When I use this code,

```
library(qdapRegex)
rf <- data.frame(rm_between_multiple(H2$SE_DESC_EN, c("\"", "\""), c("\"", "\"")))
```

it creates a data frame and for that same line earlier

```
 "Fresh or chilled Atlantic salmon and Danube salmon"
```

is returned which is perfect. However I need the missing data. To try an retain it, I change my code slightly to:

```
H3 <- rm_between_multiple(H2$SE_DESC_EN, c("\"", "\""), c("\"", "\""), extract=TRUE)
```

to create a list with the data in the quotations. That same line returned is:

```
c("Salmo salar", " and Danube salmon ", "Hucho hucho", 
  "Salmo salar", " and Danube salmon ", "Hucho hucho")
```

Which has the data in quotations but also has some info in between the quotations and is being repeated. I'm fairly new at programming and was wondering if there is a way to write a code that will not included information between these quotations.

Comment: library(qdapRegex) is the package I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need the `rm_between_multiple` just `rm_between`.  Also there appears to be a regex issue in using the same left and right marker that [I'm not sure if this is a bug yet](https://github.com/trinker/qdapRegex/issues/13).  For now you can use the following to extract

```
x <- 'Fresh or chilled Atlantic salmon "Salmo salar" and Danube salmon "Hucho hucho"'

rm_default(
    x, 
    pattern = S("@rm_between", '"'),
    extract=TRUE
)

## [[1]]
## [1] "\"Salmo salar\"" "\"Hucho hucho\""
```

**Edit** I think this is because the default regex of `rm_between` is to not include the left/right bounds.  This uses the following regex `"(?<=\").*?(?=\")"`.  This use of lookaheads cause the left/right bounds to not be consumed and thus allows the quotation marks to be available for: `" and Danube salmon "`.  This is (IMO) a bug that I will address but am unsure how yet.

**Edit 2** I incorporated @hwnd's response into `rm_between`.  The dev version of ***qdapRegex***.  You can instal the dev version via:

```
if (!require("pacman")) install.packages("pacman"); library(pacman)
p_install_gh("trinker/qdapRegex"); p_load(qdapRegex)
```

and ...

```
rm_between(x, '"', '"', extract = TRUE)

## [[1]]
## [1] "Salmo salar" "Hucho hucho"
```